# How to access this variable inside this function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, this

I have `private` variables in `constructor` and `public` variables in the `class`.

I refer to this variables and functions using `this` keyword.

I am getting `undefined` if I try to access this variables inside this function.

I am new to `typescript`, how can I access this variable inside this function?

**Technology**: Typescript, Angular 2, Angular 1.6.5, JavaScript

***admin-company-settings.ts***

```
import { Component } from '../../../../common/extentions/to-angular2';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

export class AdminCompanySettings {
    public company: any;
    constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
        //
    }

    this.company = "New company";
    console.log("Prints all public variables", this); //prints all variables

    var data = { url: www.google.com, data: { user: value } }

    this.$http(data).then(function (response) {

        console.log(response);
        console.log(this.company); // undefined cannot access company
        console.log("Prints window object", this); //this will print window 
                                                   //and not company var or 
                                                   //other scope vars
    }).catch(function (error) {

        console.log(error);

    });
}
```

I suspected it can be used by `.bind(this)` but I am not that familiar with where to add `.bind();`

https://angular.io/guide/http for ref.

Comment: you could use the arrow function expression, which preserves the value of this. make use of `() => { }` function instead of function .

Comment: Is it normal that your code is outside any `method` and that your `class` is not closed properly ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make use of Arrow function which preserves the value of `this`

```
this.$http(data).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(this.company);
        console.log("Prints window object", this);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```