# How do I consume a local variable value in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple function that returns me the value as number. This value basically how many items in a todolist is incomplete.

```
testFunction() {
    var a = 0;
    this.todos.forEach(function(elem, i) {
                    if(elem.status === true) {
                        a += 1;
                    }
                })
                console.log(a); // gives correct length
    }
```

Now in view I have

```
Total todo Items  Left <span>{{a}}</span> //Nothing coming here?
```

How do I log the value of `a` in template

Comment: Make it a property on your component

Comment: You need to define the variable as private/public outside the function, as your class member.

Comment: as a short answer, define `a` not within `var` but as `this.a = 0;`

Comment: I have done that already like so @FrankModica export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
todos : Todo[];
 a: any; 
as well as 
a: number

Comment: so you don't need to define your `a` inside of method. Remove that `var a = 0;` put instead `this.a = 0` and inside of loop use `this.a += 1`

Comment: @MysterX : i had done that initially but then  I am getting an error like.  Cannot read property 'a' of undefined

Comment: The function testFunction returns nothing. But it should return a.

Comment: @Mike You have error because additionally you need to bind `this` to the `forEach` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular can bind data to template only using own data fields of the component. So your code need to be as follows

```
testFunction() {
    this.a = 0;
    this.todos.forEach(function(elem, i) {
        if(elem.status === true) {
            this.a += 1;
        }
    }.bind(this))
    console.log(a); // gives correct length
}
```

**UPD** If you want to use ES6 syntax, you even do not need to bind `this` you can just use an arrow function which passes `this` from parent scope:

```
testFunction() {
    this.a = 0;
    this.todos.forEach((elem, i) => {
        if(elem.status === true) {
            this.a += 1;
        }
    })
    console.log(a); // gives correct length
}
```

Comment: Why  that bind sir? I missed that part I think.

Comment: Look at this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @Mike the bind is used to preserve the value of this inside of a function if not then use arraow functions [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295467/how-to-access-this-variable-inside-this-function/45295586#45295586)

Comment: If you wanted to use ES6 syntax, you would just have written `for (const elem of this.todos) { … }`