# Angular2 - Using directive to execute function in component losing scope

Tags: angular, components, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I'm using a directive to display a dialog and confirm continuation, but when returning from the directive my parent component has lost it's original scope.  The console.log will return undefined.

Process: when clicking the submit button appConfirm (directive) will handle the click event and display a dialog to continue (yes/no).  If yes is selected it will return back to my parent component and execute the submit function, but the scope is lost.

Any suggestions will be helpful.  Thanks!
A example in Plunker:  https://plnkr.co/edit/CoNqz7yv8yaGMMRRarmu

Template:

`<button [disabled]="disableButton" [(appConfirm)]="submit" style="primary" class="button-input btn btn-primary center-block">Submit</button>`

Directive:

```
import {Directive, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from '../../core/shared.service';
import {MdDialog} from "@angular/material";
import {Continue, Confirmation, ContinueConfirmation} from "../../dialog/dialog.component";
import {FormComponent} from '../../form/form.component'

@Directive({
  selector: '[appConfirm]',
})
export class ConfirmDirective {
    constructor(
        private sharedService: SharedService,
        private dialog: MdDialog
    ) {}

  @Input() appConfirm = () => {};
  @Input() confirmMessage = 'Are you sure you want to do this?';
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  confirmFirst(event: Event) {
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Confirmation,{disableClose:true});
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result=>{
               if(result) {
                  this.appConfirm();
                }

        });
  }
}
```

Component:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-form',
      templateUrl: './form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
    })
    export class FormComponent {
        myButton: string = 'test'


        submit(){
console.log(this.myButton);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Tony can you replicate a plunker

Comment: @RahulSingh - Here is an example on Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/CoNqz7yv8yaGMMRRarmu

Answer (score 4):

Updated the Plunker It works now 
[LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/H9XhcGsvKzIxXAro7YsJ?p=preview)

```
visitRangle = () => { // change is here the fat arrow function
    console.log("My button should displaY: " + this.myButton);
    console.log('Visiting rangle');
    location.href = 'https://rangle.io';
  }
```

The `this` losses it scope when used in this manner so you can use a fat arrow function to automatically bind this to the class instance:

Comment: Rahul, that works perfect. Thank you.  I just did it within my local environment and worked great.  Can you explain just a little bit what that syntax is doing?

Comment: @Tony when using normal functions the scope of this is lost and not bound when you return back from the directive either you have to add a `.bind(this)` syntax at the end of your method or you need to make use of fat arrow functions which preserve the value of this . like for this question a different kind of [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45295586/2708210)

Comment: Thanks for the quick help today.  You've saved me loads of time.  I seriously spent way too much time look for this answer.  So...thank you!